# Netsuite - Trying to create a PO from a WO on a special Item

Tags: netsuite

trying to make a PO from A work order to keep everything tied together, but as soon as I try to create the PO from the line the Dummy Component created populates with the rest of the work order not just the special Item.

Any suggestions?

I looked at a similar dummy component that was created successfully and they both look the same